# Bad Parameters in Selection (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, ms-word, selection, copy-paste, vba

I need to copy/paste table from Excel to owrd to a specific line. I have written the code and it works fine in the Excel and Word 2016 I used, but when I tried running in other versions (2013,2010,2007) it didn't work at all. So i try to use late binding, but it throws a Bad Parameters error in `.selection`

How to remove Bad Parameters? Thanks,

Here's the code :

```
Sub Movetable ()

    'Name of the existing Word document
    Const stWordDocument As String = "Test.docx"

    'Word objects.    
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdRange As Object

    'Excel objects
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range

    'Initialize the Excel objects
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Worksheets("RJ").Select

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set xlRange = Range("A4:D" & LastRow)
    xlRange.Select
    xlRange.Copy

    'Instantiate Word and open the "Test" document.
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\" & stWordDocument)

    wdDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute "Table 1. Summary", MatchCase:=True   
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdMove
    wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    wdDoc.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow


    'Save and close the Word doc.
    With wdDoc
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

    wdApp.Quit

    'Null out the variables.
    Set wdRange = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Very probably, the reason is that you've set a Refernce to the Microsoft Word library for version 2016. When you open and run the project in an earlier version, the reference doesn't change to the Microsoft Word library for that version. This is expected behavior.

To fix the problem you can either

1. Open the project in the earliest version of Office (2007,
   apparently). Go to Tools/References in the VBA Editor and select the
   Microsoft Word library for that version. Test, then save.

   Office applications *will* change References to a newer version, but they don't do so the other way around. That's why it's always recommended to develop using the oldest version of Office the project should work in.
2. Don't use named arguments in the method calls. Remove, for example, `MatchCase:=`, `Unit`, `Count`, `Extend`. In addition, don't use the Word enumerations: `wdLine`, `wdMove`, `wdAutoFitWindow`- these all have numerical equivalents, use those instead.

This is known as "late-binding", which makes your project independent of the version of Word. You can then completely remove the Reference to the Microsoft Word library.

In order to find out the numerical equivalents you can look up the enumerations in the VBA Object Browser (F2 in the VBA Editor), look them up in the Word VBA Help or query them in the VBA Editor Immediate Window (Ctrl + G) using syntax like this: `?wdLine` and then press Enter to execute.

Comment: Thankyou. I still use Excel 2016. For .Selection method, I have removed named arguments and word enumarations. But it only works when References Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library on. I also try other codes without .Selection method and it can works without Reference (but this is not what i want). What should i do next?

Comment: Exactly which line(s) of code are throwing errors in other versions of Office?